# Swift class not conforming to Objective C Protocol

Tags: objective-c, swift, protocols

I have this objective c protocol as mentioned below:

```
@protocol Class1<NSObject>

- (void)searchBy:(Enum1)searchType;

@end
```

And i am trying to make a swift class conform to that protocol . The stub which Xcode generated for me is as follows:

```
func search(by searchType: Enum1) {
}
```

But Xcode gives me an error while building that the class still doesn’t conform to protocol. What am i missing here?

Comment: have you tried cleaning your project?

Comment: tried. didn't work..

Comment: Don't name a protocol `Class1`. Why does `Class1` conform to `NSObject`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your Objective-C header that contains the protocol and enum in the bridging header for swift to find?

So I created a new test app, and the view controller looks as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, Class1
{
    func search(by searchType: Enum1) {
        print("it works")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let class1 = self as Class1
        class1.search(by: Enum1.PlayerStateOff)
    }
}
```

And my objective-C bridging header looks like this:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "Foo.h"
```

And the ObjectiveC header Foo.h looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Enum1) {
    PlayerStateOff,
    PlayerStatePlaying,
    PlayerStatePaused
};

@protocol Class1<NSObject>

- (void)searchBy:(Enum1)searchType;

@end

@interface Foo : NSObject

@end
```

And it all compiles, runs, and prints "it works" just fine in Xcode 9.2.  So it's probably your bridging header, but double-check everything you're doing against the above.

Comment: `UIViewController` and `NSObject` conform to `NSObject`.